# How to get EObject from EObjectNode

Tags: java, eclipse, xtext

In an independent ViewPart I managed to get the EObjectNode selected in the OutlineView. I now need to get the EObject it refers to but I can't see how.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (selection instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
        Object first = ((IStructuredSelection)selection).getFirstElement();
        EObjectNode enode = (EObjectNode)first;
        ResourceSet resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl();
        Resource inResource = resourceSet.getResource(enode.getEObjectURI(),true);
        MyEcoreElement element = (MyEcoreElement)inResource.getEObject(enode.getEObjectURI().fragment());
        //....  
 }
```